# Encrypt data in URL or use key to access it in database?

Tags: encryption, model-view-controller, key, url-routing, sails.js

A small-scale web site, with content pages generated from a small amount of data: maximum six integers.

I'm wondering how to optimally design the URLs that point to these pages, so that users can't manually change the URL to change the displayed data.

This is a node.js + mongoDB project, with an MVC structure (actually via sails.js, even if it's probably not relevant here).

Let's say the pattern looks like `http://domain.com/xxxxxx`

• **Approach 1: encryption.**
`xxxxxx` carries the six integers and a control key, encrypted via a simple library. The server decrypts the URL and serves the page and embedded data.

Pros: fast, smaller disk space since no need to maintain a database collection for this

• **Approach 2: database.**
I define a model to keep track of all data sets (the six integers) that are created by users.
In the URL, `xxxxxx` is the model's primary key. Data is retrieved from accessing the database.

Pros: analytics, ie: by enriching the model, it's possibile to track past usage and statistics

For now, I'm thinking that analytics are the only justification to Approach 2. If I don't need them, is there a risk to choosing Approach 1, and are the listed advantages meaningful?

Comment: Are you wanting to prevent users from easily guessing a valid URL? If so, then I would either: (A) Randomly allocate URLs from a significantly larger space of integers; or (B) Implement user access control, so that users are disallowed from viewing pages they are not meant to.

Comment: (A) comes down to the same as my approach 2, ie involving a database, so that the server can track what content is related to what integer. Encryption enables to have no randomness, while still hiding the URL logics. (B) is not relevant here, there's no content that must really be forbidden to users, I just don't want them to find the contents easily (it's a mini-game)